# Geo-location with leaflet in JS

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet

The following JS script (CSS/HTML included for completeness) is intended to open the leaflet map tiles and mark the user location. While it opens the map, it doesn't mark the user location. Why not?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Leaflet GeoLocation</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            html, body, #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            var map = L.map('map').setView([43, -79], 18);
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
                maxZoom: 18
            }).addTo(map);
            var newMarker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not trying to get the user location at any point in this code.
This line :

```
var newMarker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
```

`e` is not defined in the code you provide. So you need to give it a latitude/longitude value.

Comment: Thank you. The following corrects and fixes it.

   function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
     .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();
    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
   }
   
   function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
   }

   map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
   map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

   map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});